# How to exclude nested directories in grep command?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I want to search for the word `disable_mlock` in the current directory and its subfolders. For that, I use:

```
sam@sam-Dell:~/Desktop$ grep -r disable_mlock
a/vault/config/vault-config.hcl:disable_mlock=true
b/vault/config/vault-config.hcl:disable_mlock=true
vault/config/vault-config.hcl:disable_mlock=true
```

Then, I would like to exclude only the `vault/config/` subdirectory:

```
sam@sam-Dell:~/Desktop$ grep -r --exclude-dir=vault/config/
a/vault/config/vault-config.hcl:disable_mlock=true
b/vault/config/vault-config.hcl:disable_mlock=true
vault/config/vault-config.hcl:disable_mlock=true
```

And it does not work.

Then I try to exclude only the `vault/` dir:

```
sam@sam-Dell:~/Desktop$ grep -r disable_mlock --exclude-dir=vault
sam@sam-Dell:~/Desktop$
```

It returns nothing... probably because `vault/` is in the path of every result.

If I exclude `config/`:

```
sam@sam-Dell:~/Desktop$ grep -r disable_mlock --exclude-dir=config/
sam@sam-Dell:~/Desktop$
```

No result appears, too - all of the matches were below a `config/` directory. But I just want to exclude one of those `config/` dirs, the `vault/config/`, not all of them!

I conclude grep can only exclude one directory at a time, whether a direct one or a deep one, relatively to the current directory. In this case it is an issue for me because I have paths that have similar directories.

I cannot find, then, a way of **excluding specific nested subdirectories** with `grep`. Is there a way to do it *with grep*?

Comment: @MTilsted I didn't understand it, but tried `grep disable_mlock --exclude-dir=vault/ * */ *` and didn't work

Comment: You could re-grep the output and exclude the phrase?

Comment: In this particular situation, you might as well use this simple glob: `grep -r disable_mlock */vault/config`.

Comment: You could use `find` to exec `grep` on the found files? Remember you will need to specify -H if you want grep to print the filename.

Answer (score 1):

Are you accept pipe in your command or do you want it in one shot?
With pipe:

```
grep -r disable_mlock * | egrep -v "^vault"
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU `find` provides more options than `grep` to exclude paths:

```
find -path ./vault/config -prune -o -type f -exec grep pattern {} +
```

`-prune` combined with `-path path_expression` instructs `find` to ignore the specified path. `-exec grep ...` does the actual search.

This command won't follow symbolic links, contrary to `grep`, which may or may not be a good thing, depending on your needs. Use the `-L` option if you need to follow them.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you strictly want to use `grep` command which means no piping or other alternative commands that would work better. If you're in a hurry, check out the last code.

First of all, a word of caution! If you take a look at the man page of the `grep` command, you find this syntax for `--exclude-dir` option,

```
 --exclude-dir=PATTERN
```

It means that the option **only** accepts pattern as the input. You cannot use a **pathname** for it. That's why your search with `--exclude-dir=vault/config` didn't work. Because it didn't exclude the config subdirectory within the vault directory, it actually excludes every single directory that has 'vault/config' in its name which there is none.

So by knowing this, it simply means that the option is useless for this context. But we have to somehow extend the "clue" and let the command to know exactly which directories we want to search. First, take another look at `grep` command syntax,

```
grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
```

**TL;DR** The way I do this is,

```
grep -r disable_mlock ?/vault/config
```

I simply used an exclusive file pathname. The question mark (?) is a wildcard which stands for a "single character". That's because I know all the directories which I want to search in, have only one letter as their name.